# Instagram Rate Limiting Per IP?

Tags: api, instagram

I'm developing/scaling a multitenant SAAS platform in which we fetch Instagram content (amongst other social networks) for them based on their search criteria.  We currently use OAuth for them to sign in with their Instagram account and then poll Instagrams API every 15 seconds per access token for new content and updates to old content.

As we've had more users we've noticed that we've been starting to receive a lot of OAuthRateLimitException's even though we should still be well below the rate limit.

My understanding is that Instagram allows for 5,000 calls per hour per access token which comes out to a max of a bit over 1 call per second.  Since we're calling once per 15 seconds we should be well under that limit.  From reading the docs they seems to have different rate limits for some of the endpoints however we're using only the following endpoints which don't seem to have special rate limits:

```
/users/{user-id}/media/recent
/tags/{tag-name}/media/recent
/users/{user-id}
/media/{media-id}
```

All of these requests are being made as GETs with the access token of the signed in user so I'm a bit stumped as to what is going on.  From the logging I've confirmed that we are in fact only calling once per 15 seconds per access token although I've noticed that the OAuthRateLimitException's are happening just about all at once for every single access token we're using which leads me to believe that they may have some sort of rate limit per IP or per app?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

-Lee

Comment: are u just making one API call every 15sec or is it paginating and making multiple calls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel stupid,
Turns out I had some bad error handling which would retry the API calls when they failed (which happens a lot with 500 internal server errors).  Apparently the calls which were failing we're counting against the rate limit but they we're being debug logged...